# stop background music in a different scene in cocos2d

Tags: iphone

how to stop the background music in different scenes in cocos2d.Like in enabled sound option if we press "no" option the background music in another scene will stop and "yes" option will also do the same task. please help me i am new in cocos2d game development

Answer (score 0):

Declare player and also set one variable or flag in app delegate class. By the help of this you can easily check it in any class of your application. So in scene where you want to stop your music, set your flag false and stop player....